# Permanently delete emails listed by "notmuch search" command?

Tags: email, notmuch

What's the easiest way to permanently delete emails with notmuch?

[Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Notmuch#Permanently_delete_emails) recommends the following snippet:

`notmuch search --output=files --format=text0 <search-term> | xargs -r0 rm`

You must however put arguments directly after `search` otherwise it won't work. You most likely will also want to run `notmuch new` after to refresh the index.

I'm thinking that if you're a zsh user it'll be easiest to write a zle function:

```
notmuch-rm () {
  emulate -L zsh
  local words=(${(z)BUFFER})
  BUFFER="$words[1,2] --output=files --format=text0 $words[3,-1] | xargs -r0 rm"
}
zle -N notmuch-rm
```

[reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/13zazka/how_to_add_words_in_the_middle_of_the_buffer/)

I wonder if anyone could think of a better way to do it? "Better" as in the least amount of button presses and least amount of maintenance mental overhead. I realize that it may sound silly, but if you have to repeat this action hundred times every day it would be nice to simplify it.